# vim: is there a plugin to show all of your TODO tags in source?

Tags: vim, macvim

Like most of you, I work in several source files of code every day. A lot of the time, my insane work flow has me doing stuff like:

```
# TODO
# clean up this code
# do something else with this code
```

Is there currently a vim plugin available that will search for TODO or a similar mnemonic and print a list of my current tasks that are on-going and in what source file it needs to be done? It would be a huge time saver instead of using grep constantly. Also with vim ctags, you can jump right in the code where you left the TODO off at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've not tried it (yet), but [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2607) plugin looks promising.

Edit:  I've just tried this plugin out.  I will be keeping it around.  It's very handy and interactively moves you around the buffer while you navigate the task list.

Also, there is a [mirror](https://github.com/vim-scripts/TaskList.vim) on github if you use pathogen or another means of git submodules for your vim directory.

Answer (score 9):

When you say `grep`, are you talking about grep from the command line, or `:grep` in vim?  The latter allows you to view a quickfix list of matches and jump to them.  If typing out `:grep TODO -r .` becomes cumbersome you could easily map that operation to a hotkey.

Comment: the ":grep TODO -r *" command looks nice! can you explain how to jump to e.g. the 3rd occurrence when displaying the result output?

Comment: Check out the docs for the quickfix list: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html (or just `:help quickfix`).  Also note that you can switch windows to the quickfix list and navigate with the usual vim motions; `Enter` will jump to the line in the file.